# sh: make: not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, make

I got the following error message:

```
sh: make: not found
```

I guess I need to install make, or a compiler on my Ubuntu 9.04

Could you tell me what I exactly need to type to install it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

build-essential is a package which contains stuff needed for building software. (make, gcc ..)

Comment: you meant sudo apt-get install build-essential right ?

Comment: yeah cool it worked